# sorting a list of countries in descending order and returning the nth country

Tags: python, sorting, search

I am trying to work with a function called `countryByPop()` that takes an integer as a parameter.Function does two things:
First, get the list of countries(from a text file called `"countries.text"`), and sort it in descending order of population using the selection sort algorithm. 
Second, use the integer parameter and return the nth most populace country.

`readCountries()` is a method that i created to open a file `"countries.text"` and displaying it.
the results looks like this eventually `[Name, Area, Population]`:

```
[["Afghanistan",647500.0,25500100],["Albania",28748.0,2821977].......["Zimbabwe",390580.0,12973808]]
```

Now, I am done with the the first(sorting) part of the function:

```
def countryByPop():
    Countries = readCountries()
    for i in range(0,len(Countries)):
        madeSwap = False
        for j in range (0,len(Countries)-(i+1)):
            if Countries[j][2] < Countries[j+1][2]:
                temp = Countries[j+1]
                Countries[j+1] = Countries[j]
                Countries[j] = temp
                madeSwap = True
        if not madeSwap:
            return Countries
    return Countries
```

I can not seem to figure out the how to return the nth most popular country.

lets say i pass 18 as an integer parameter in the function, and 18 gives you Turkey as the 18th most populated city in the list, it should print out something like:

```
>>>>countryByPop(18) 
["Turkey",780580.0,75627384]

>>>countryByPop(-1)
Invalid parameter: -1
```

Comment: You already access country by number in your sorting function. What is the problem now?

Comment: do you mean `Countries[n]` ?

Comment: You comment below that you were instructed to use selection sort, but I'm wondering if you were not supposed to do a full sort but instead find the kth (nth) element using quick select, which only does a partial sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all there is no `n` parameter in the signature of the function, wihch should instead be

```
def countryByPop(n):
```

then, at the end, assuming Countries is ordered, you need to return its `n-th` value

```
return Countries[n]
```

Note: python allows you to return tuples so in case you need to return the sorted list and the nth element you can do

```
return Countries, Countries[n]
```

In my humble opinion, it is simpler to just return the list and have the caller access its `n-th` element

Further notes:

- please follow the [PEP-8 guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for naming variables
- do not re-invent the wheel and use python's own sorting
  functionalities (in-place with the list `sort` method or using `sorted`)

Answer (score 2):

Python already has methods for sorting lists of sequences in the way you need. For example,

```
# sort the list of lists countries, ordering by the third element in reverse
countries.sort(key=lambda e: -e[2])
# the 10th most populous country:
countries[10]
```

That is, you can tell the `sort` method to order the elements of `countries` (which happen to be lists of 3 elements themselves) in order of increasing (-population): ie decreasing population. Then the first element of the sorted list will be to most populous country and so on.

Comment: i appreciate your help, and I also know about the sort method from python. But I had some strict instructions to use the selection sort algorithm.